# Get Value of array name in react js in functional componet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How can I get value with input name array in functional component based react js.

Here is my code

```html
<form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <input type="text" name="otp[]"  placeholder="0" className="form-control inputs"/>
   <input type="text" name="otp[]"  placeholder="0" className="form-control inputs"/>
   <input type="text" name="otp[]"  placeholder="0" className="form-control inputs"/>
   <input type="text" name="otp[]"  placeholder="0" className="form-control inputs"/>
   <button className="btn btn-default text-light pos-rel">Verify</button>
 </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. `How can I get value with input name array in functional component based react js`. add and onChange to your inputs and get the input name from the event. `event.target.name` and value is `event.target.value`

Comment: I am using  
<input type="text" name="otp[]" maxLength={1}  placeholder="0" className="fom-control inputs" onChange={e => setOTP(e.target.value)}
                    />
but getting only one value.
const [otp, setOTP] = useState();
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(otp)
  }

Comment: From what I know the syntax `name="otp[]"` has no particular effect besides PHP. You're getting a single value because your `onChange` handler is overwriting the component's state every time with `e.target.value` and that is the single value of a single input element

Comment: So , How can I can value of name="otp[]" .please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store input values with state, for this i suggest an object.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({otp1: 0, otp2: 0, ...restOfTheInputs });
```

Then you can trigger a change of state when an input is changed by adding a onChange prop to your inputs. (You should also give these inputs a unique name)

```
<input type="text" name="otp1" value={values.opt1} onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} />
```

in this function you will want to update state with the new value for the input replacing any old value while keeping any values from the other inputs.

```
const handleInput = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setValues(currentValue => ({...currentValue, ...{name: value}}))
}
```